Repositioning PopupMenuButton in flutter
i have try to create a popup menu button but i want to reposition the menu.
this is the code i've tried :
PopupMenuButton(itemBuilder: (context)=>[
        PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Grup Baru")),
        PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Siaran Baru")),
        PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Perangkat Tertaut")),
        PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Pesan Berbintang")),
      ])

and here's the result for default :

and i want to reposition it,
to this :

is there any suggest that i can try?

Add position: PopupMenuPosition.under, inside PopupMenuButton widget.
Refer position and PopupMenuPosition
under: Menu is positioned under the anchor.
Full widget:
PopupMenuButton(
        position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Grup Baru")),
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Siaran Baru")),
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Perangkat Tertaut")),
          PopupMenuItem(child: Text("Pesan Berbintang")),
        ],
      ),

Result Screen: 

Most welcome glad to help you out. Enjoy your ride with flutter.
